# Convert from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following code gives me the display that I want.  The only modification that I want is to specify the points in polar coordinates with the same radius. (These points are on a unit circle centered at (0,1). In polar coordinates, `A` is the vector sum of `(1:72)=(1:pi/5)` and `(0,1)`, `B` is the vector sum of `(1:144)=(1:2pi/5)` and `(0,1)`, and `C` is the vector sum of `(1:288)=(1:4pi5)` and `(0,1)`.)  I want to use the `TikZ` environment to perform the calculations to place the points precisely.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,samples=501,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-0.5,ymax=2.5,
restrict y to domain=-0.5:2.5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={draw=gray!30,latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\draw (axis cs:0.309016994375,1.951056516295) coordinate(A) node[above right]{$A$};
\draw (axis cs:-0.809016994375,1.587785252292) coordinate(B) node[above]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:0.309016994375, 0.048943483705) coordinate(C) node[below]{$C$};

\draw (0,1) circle (1);
\end{axis}

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to know: why to use such complicated coordinates?

Comment: I am using this example as a model.  I would adapt the code provided to the situation that I have.  (I also want to know how to have `TikZ` or `pgfplots` do such calculations for me.  It would make coding for a triangle inscribed in a circle as easy as coding for a dodecagon in a circle.)

Comment: This could help you: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/regular-polygons/

Comment: "Measurement should be specified in terms of the coordinate system, using the `axis` environment, instead of in terms of the metric system."  The code at the web site you provided uses `xshift` commands to position the centers of the circles.

Comment: The editing that my code needs should be minimal, I think.  People must position circles using `axis` environment.  In my code, I positioned the points using the `axis` environment.

Comment: What you give are not polar coordinates. They are regular coordinates with `pi` in them. Please clarify what you mean. What do you mean you want to use tikz environment. What is all that axis stuff needed anyway? Can you cut down to the lines you want to modify and get rid of the rest?

Comment: @percusse  You are right.  What I wrote was confusing.  I have edited the post and stated that I want `TikZ` to perform the calculations to place the points precisely.  See the code provided by `Torbjørn T.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to plot the circle and lines with parametric coordinates for `\addplot`. Your circle and triangle would become

```
\addplot [samples=200,domain=0:360] ({cos(x)},{1+sin(x)});
\addplot [samples at={72,144,288,72}] ({cos(x)},{1+sin(x)});
```

The labels for the points can be added with e.g.

```
\node at ({cos(72)},{1+sin(72)}) [above right] {$A$};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,samples=501,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-0.5,ymax=2.5,
restrict y to domain=-0.5:2.5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={draw=gray!30,latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
]
\addplot [samples=200,domain=0:360] ({cos(x)},{1+sin(x)});
\addplot [samples at={72,144,288,72}] ({cos(x)},{1+sin(x)});

\node at ({cos(72)},{1+sin(72)}) [above right] {$A$};
\node at ({cos(144)},{1+sin(144)}) [above left] {$B$};
\node at ({cos(288)},{1+sin(288)}) [below] {$C$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```