# TIkZ-pic (with sub-pics) won't scale

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have read [Convert from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227531/convert-from-rectangular-coordinates-to-polar-coordinates) but didn't find a solution for me.

I have defined a `pic` named `compass` which I plan to use several times in different scaled version (and with rotated with an different angle).

I was able to define a second `pic` named `yacht`, which is relocatable, scalable and rotatable.  The only difference is, that I used polar coordinates, to construct the compass rose.

Here is an example document of the intended usage:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A} ;
  \path pic (b) at ([xshift=5cm] a) {yacht} ;
  \pic [below=2cm of a, scale=.4, rotate=220] (c) {yacht} ;
  \pic [scale=.2, rotate=120, right=2cm of c-yacht] (d) {yacht} ;
  \pic [below=8cm of d-yacht, scale=.2, rotate=60] (error) {compass} ;
  \pic [right=9cm of error-compass ] (error) {compass} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(For comparison, the first call of the `yacht` is unscaled and not rotated.)

This is the result.

[image: Example of the non scaling compass rose]

What went wrong?

Here is the complete MWE (I removed the definition of the `yacht`to keep it small).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% Lade weitere Pakete
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning}



\def\needle{50}
\def\short{\needle/10}
\newcommand{\needlelength}[1]{\def\needle{#1}}

\tikzset{
  rose/.style = {
    % xscale      = 1/2,
    % yscale      = 1/2,
    % scale       = 0.2,
    font        =\large,
    semithick,
  },
  leftrose/.style = {
    rose,
    fill = black!70,
  },
  rightrose/.style = {
    fill = black!10,
  },
}

\tikzset{
  pics/compassneedle/.style 2 args={
    code={
      %% Try to draw a needle by aims of polar coordinates.
      \filldraw[leftrose]
      % start at origin, 
      (0:0)
      % move nw for the short distance
      -- ({#1+45}:{\short*\needle})
      % reach the tip at north
      -- ({#1}:{\needle})
      % go back to origin
      -- cycle ;
      % repeat the same on the eastern side.
      \filldraw[rightrose]
      % start at origin, 
      (0:0)
      % move ne for the short distance
      -- ({#1-45}:{\short*\needle})
      % reach the tip at north
      -- ({#1}:{\needle})
      % go back to origin
      -- cycle ;
      %%
      %% Insert the direction
      \node[rotate={#1-90}] at ({#1}:{1.1*\needle}) {#2} ;
    }
  }, % end of compassneedle
}

\tikzset{%
  pics/compass/.style={
    code={
      %% Position a named node here
      \node (-compass) {};

      %% Begin with a layer of the rose pointing to ne, nw, sw, se.
      %% This layer shall be somewhat shorter than the main layer.
      \needlelength{3.5}
      \foreach \angle/\name in {45/NE, 135/NW, 225/SW, 315/SE} {
        \pic{compassneedle={\angle}{\name}} ;
      }
      %% Next, put a second layer with the main directions.  Don't
      %% forget to increase the needle lengths accordingly.
      \needlelength{4}
      \foreach  \angle/\name in {0/E, 90/N, 180/W, 270/S} {
        \pic{compassneedle={\angle}{\name}} ;
      }
    }
  },
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [scale=.2] (error) {compass} ;
  \pic [right=9cm of error-compass ] (error) {compass} ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}%
```

Comment: This is normal because `scale` in some scope only scale the coordinates and not the nodes, pics, fonts, line width, .... You have different choices : use `transform canvas={scale=...}`, or pass the scale as parameter to the compass, and then apply it to the sub-pics, or simply do not use sub-pics.

Comment: @Kpym thanks for the insight.  Not using pics is (right now) the least desirable option for me.  I'll give the `transform canvas={scale=}` a try.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a (golf type) example of `\pic{compass}` that can be scaled and styled.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  compass/.pic = {
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\m=div(\i-1,4);\a=90*\i-45*(\m+1)}] \d in {NE,NW,SW,SE,E,N,W,S}{
      \filldraw[pic actions,rotate=\a,scale=.7+.3*\m] (0,0) -- (45:1)--(0:3) node[transform shape,rotate=-90,above]{\d};
      \filldraw[pic actions,fill=white,rotate=\a,scale=.7+.3*\m] (0,0) -- (-45:1)--(0:3)--cycle;
    };
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic{compass};
    \pic[scale=.7,fill=red,text=blue] at (7,0) {compass};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow :-), that is really impressive!

Comment: 'Golf type'? Like a golf ball? Confused .... (+1 for the rest - just I don't get the description.)

Comment: @cfr like [code colf(ing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Kpym in his comment, one can use the option `transform canvas={scale=...}`.

So instead of

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [scale=.2] (error) {compass} ;
  \pic [right=9cm of error-compass ] (full-size) {compass} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

you should use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [transform canvas={scale=.2}] (error) {compass} ;
  \pic [right=9cm of error-compass ] (full-size) {compass} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This has worked for me, but it placed the `pic` in the middle of my picture.  So you have to add some correcting movements in x and y also!

Comment: Instead of `transform canvas`, here `\pic [scale=.2, transform shape] (error) {compass} ;` would be the way to go for nodes to pick up the transformations

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `\resizebox{width}{height}{what you want to resize}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% Lade weitere Pakete
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning}



\def\needle{50}
\def\short{\needle/10}
\newcommand{\needlelength}[1]{\def\needle{#1}}

\tikzset{
  rose/.style = {
    % xscale      = 1/2,
    % yscale      = 1/2,
    % scale       = 0.2,
    font        =\large,
    semithick,
  },
  leftrose/.style = {
    rose,
    fill = black!70,
  },
  rightrose/.style = {
    fill = black!10,
  },
}

\tikzset{
  pics/compassneedle/.style 2 args={
    code={
      %% Try to draw a needle by aims of polar coordinates.
      \filldraw[leftrose]
      % start at origin, 
      (0:0)
      % move nw for the short distance
      -- ({#1+45}:{\short*\needle})
      % reach the tip at north
      -- ({#1}:{\needle})
      % go back to origin
      -- cycle ;
      % repeat the same on the eastern side.
      \filldraw[rightrose]
      % start at origin, 
      (0:0)
      % move ne for the short distance
      -- ({#1-45}:{\short*\needle})
      % reach the tip at north
      -- ({#1}:{\needle})
      % go back to origin
      -- cycle ;
      %%
      %% Insert the direction
      \node[rotate={#1-90}] at ({#1}:{1.1*\needle}) {#2} ;
    }
  }, % end of compassneedle
}

\tikzset{%
  pics/compass/.style={
    code={
      %% Position a named node here
      \node (-compass) {};

      %% Begin with a layer of the rose pointing to ne, nw, sw, se.
      %% This layer shall be somewhat shorter than the main layer.
      \needlelength{3.5}
      \foreach \angle/\name in {45/NE, 135/NW, 225/SW, 315/SE} {
        \pic{compassneedle={\angle}{\name}} ;
      }
      %% Next, put a second layer with the main directions.  Don't
      %% forget to increase the needle lengths accordingly.
      \needlelength{4}
      \foreach  \angle/\name in {0/E, 90/N, 180/W, 270/S} {
        \pic{compassneedle={\angle}{\name}} ;
      }
    }
  },
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{10cm}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pic (error) {compass} ;
            \pic [right=9cm of error-compass ] (error) {compass} ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

That way, you don't have the problem with the `transform canvas={scale=...}` where it has problems with the surroundings.

Edit: new way

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig} %% NEW PACKAGE
%% Lade weitere Pakete
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning}
\def\needle{50}
\def\short{\needle/10}
\newcommand{\needlelength}[1]{\def\needle{#1}}
\tikzset{
  rose/.style = {
    % xscale      = 1/2,
    % yscale      = 1/2,
    % scale       = 0.2,
    font        =\large,
    semithick,
  },
  leftrose/.style = {
    rose,
    fill = black!70,
  },
  rightrose/.style = {
    fill = black!10,
  },
}
\tikzset{
  pics/compassneedle/.style 2 args={
    code={
      %% Try to draw a needle by aims of polar coordinates.
      \filldraw[leftrose]
      % start at origin, 
      (0:0)
      % move nw for the short distance
      -- ({#1+45}:{\short*\needle})
      % reach the tip at north
      -- ({#1}:{\needle})
      % go back to origin
      -- cycle ;
      % repeat the same on the eastern side.
      \filldraw[rightrose]
      % start at origin, 
      (0:0)
      % move ne for the short distance
      -- ({#1-45}:{\short*\needle})
      % reach the tip at north
      -- ({#1}:{\needle})
      % go back to origin
      -- cycle ;
      %%
      %% Insert the direction
      \node[rotate={#1-90}] at ({#1}:{1.1*\needle}) {#2} ;
    }
  }, % end of compassneedle
}
\tikzset{%
  pics/compass/.style={
    code={
      %% Position a named node here
      \node (-compass) {};

      %% Begin with a layer of the rose pointing to ne, nw, sw, se.
      %% This layer shall be somewhat shorter than the main layer.
      \needlelength{3.5}
      \foreach \angle/\name in {45/NE, 135/NW, 225/SW, 315/SE} {
        \pic{compassneedle={\angle}{\name}} ;
      }
      %% Next, put a second layer with the main directions.  Don't
      %% forget to increase the needle lengths accordingly.
      \needlelength{4}
      \foreach  \angle/\name in {0/E, 90/N, 180/W, 270/S} {
        \pic{compassneedle={\angle}{\name}} ;
      }
    }
  },
}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{
        \raisebox{10mm}{
            \resizebox{3cm}{3cm}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \pic (error) {compass} ;
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
    }
    \subfloat{
        \resizebox{5cm}{5cm}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \pic [right= 9cm of error-compass,anchor=center ] (error) {compass} ;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Second way leads to

[image]

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: this time the complete picture is scaled, instead of fitting only the compass part into it.

Comment: @Jan added a second answer.