# TikZ pic "compass" won't compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive-2016, texlive-2017

A few days ago user [Kpym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9335/kpym) created a nice piece of code to draw a TikZ pic of the compass, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424688/120477.

For me, this solution works as a charme.  But for my fellow co-worker, it does not compile, but gives the error message

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'div' has not yet been
>   implemented in the floating point unit (in 'div(1-1,4)')

Funny fact: I am using TeXLive, version `tlmgr revision 41476 (2016-06-18 02:45:25 +0200)`, while my colleague uses a newer version: `tlmgr revision 44422 (2017-05-19 17:07:25 +0200)`

So it used to work in the older TeX Live version of 2016, but refuses to work in the version 2017.

What is going wrong?

Comment: In the frozen TeXLive 2017 (revision 46207) it works like a charm.

Comment: @Skillmon, thanks for your input, we will run an update, I will report later on.

Comment: Do your co-workers use `fpu` ? It looks like there is a [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336520/9335) with `div` when used with `fpu`.

Comment: As workaround you can use `int((\i-1)/4)` in place of `div(\i-1,4)`. Or you can use in this example `\m=\i<5?0:1;` because `\m` is `0` when `\i=1,...,4` and is `1` for `\i=5,...,8`.

Comment: @Kpym I don't know but have asked him.